# How can I pass Java SystemProperties to a Gradle JunitTest

Tags: intellij-idea, junit, gradle

I got a JUnit test that relies upon a Java SystemProperty (more precisely the library used in it relies on it).
I want to start the JUnit test from IntelliJ. Therefore I edited the run configuration and added VM options like "-DpropertyName=value". IntelliJ then starts gradle with something like this:

```
gradle cleanTest test --tests com.example.Test -DpropertyName=value
```

When I check from my Test with System.getProperty() / getProperties() the property was not passed and thus is null.

How can i pass the properties to the JunitTest?

Answer (score 10):

As it turns out, IntelliJ can only pass those JVM options to the JVM gradle runs in and gradle will not pass those to the tests. To specify a property for the JVM that will run the tests, either edit the `build.gradle` file and add:

```
test {
  systemProperty 'propertyName', 'value'
}
```

or, instead, add

```
test.jvmArgs System.getProperty("test.jvmArgs").split(" ")
```

to the `build.gradle` file and modify your run configuration VM options to be something like

```
-Dtest.jvmArgs="-DpropertyName=value -Dprop2=value2"
```

Comment: I had the same problem and adding systemProperty to build.gradle fixed it for me (the first part of this answer). But I don't understand (in the OR part of your answer) where I'd put : test.jvmArgs System.getProperty("test.jvmArgs").split(" ") ?

Comment: @Pierre: I did not understood that as well, for a while. Now I understand: The first part uses properties hardcoded in `build.gradle`. The second alternative allows you to pass the properties from the run configuration, by adding one _general_ rule to the `build.gradle` file, and passing the specific values using a (invented, nothing Gradle-defined) property `test.jvmArgs`.

Comment: Option#2 is brilliant!